# Detecting whether a module is imported inside the App Engine environment

Tags: python, google-app-engine

What I want to do is patch an existing Python module that uses urllib2 to run on App Engine, but I don't want to break it so it can be used elsewhere. So I'm looking for a quick solution to test if the module is imported in the App Engine environment or not. Catching ImportError on urllib2 might not be the best solution.

Answer (score 11):

You could simply use sys.modules to test if a module has been imported (I'm using unicodedata as an example):

```
>>> import sys
>>> 'unicodedata' in sys.modules
False
>>> import unicodedata
>>> 'unicodedata' in sys.modules
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a simple check against key environment variables. No telling exactly how reliable this might be, though.

```
import os, logging
try:
  os.environ['APPENGINE_RUNTIME']
except KeyError:
  logging.warn('We are not in App Engine environment')
else:
  logging.info('We are in the App Engine environment')
```

You can also [define your own custom environment variable in your App Engine configuration file](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Defining_Environment_Variables) and that will be viewable from `os.environ` within any module. So, type something like this in your app.yaml file:

```
env_variables:
  MY_APP_ENGINE_ENVIRONMENT: '982844ed9cbd6ce42318d2804386be29cbc7c35a'
```

... will give you an unambiguous ID to reference.

From the development server, here are the environment variables that I get:

```
{'USER_EMAIL': '',
 'DATACENTER': 'us1',
 'wsgi.version': (1, 0),
 'REQUEST_ID_HASH': 'E2C19D51',
 'SERVER_NAME': 'mydesktop',
 'QUERY_STRING': '',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
 'APPENGINE_RUNTIME': 'python27',
 'wsgi.input': <cStringIO.StringI object at 0x2f145d0>,
 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1',
 'HTTPS': 'off',
 'USER_IS_ADMIN': '0',
 'TZ': 'UTC',
 'REMOTE_ADDR': '192.168.0.2',
 'HTTP_X_APPENGINE_COUNTRY': 'ZZ',
 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36',
 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Development/2.0',
 'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL': 'max-age=0',
 'DEFAULT_VERSION_HOSTNAME': 'mydesktop:8080',
 'SERVER_PORT': '8080',
 'wsgi.run_once': False,
 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',
 'USER_ID': '',
 'AUTH_DOMAIN': 'gmail.com',
 'USER_NICKNAME': '',
 'USER_ORGANIZATION': '',
 'wsgi.multiprocess': True,
 'INSTANCE_ID': '8a8e02e6efa8d195346ae0c90cfeafce8aa2',
 'PATH_INFO': '/',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
 'HTTP_HOST': 'mydesktop:8080',
 'wsgi.errors': <google.appengine.api.logservice.logservice.LogsBuffer object at 0x2f09c30>,
 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~myapp',
 'wsgi.multithread': True,
 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': 'version-1',
 'SCRIPT_NAME': '',
 'REQUEST_LOG_ID': '4eafbc91ca4ebd5fee53f19eeab2eb26d243d9ddc92b6b9bc0a063eabdc84cfff',
 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http'}
```

Hope that helps.